# undefined Reference to "_ZNSt5__padIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6_S_padERSt8ios_basecPcPKcllb" symbol is not exported from libstdc++.a(libstdc++.so.6)

Tags: c++, linker, aix, libstdc++, gcc4.8

I am able to build my code successfully but getting following error while trying to run it. I am on **AIX7.1** using **GCC4.8.5**.

`0509-130 Symbol resolution failed for libadobelinguistic.a because:
        0509-136   Symbol _ZNSt5__padIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6_S_padERSt8ios_basecPcPKcllb (number 94) is not exported from
                   dependent module /user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/lib/libstdc++.a(libstdc++.so.6).
        0509-022 Cannot load module .
        0509-026 System error: Cannot run a file that does not have a valid format.
        0509-192 Examine .loader section symbols with the
                 'dump -Tv' command."}`

As suggested at few places I used `-Wl,--no-undefined` flag to fail the project at compilation time. but compilation is not failing.

**demangled function**:

`std::__pad<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_S_pad(std::ios_base&, char, char*, char const*, long, long, bool)`

I am unable to find reference to this function.

Moreover as suggested at few places In case of such errors you need to set `LIBPATH` variable in case of AIX. I have libpath variable set to

```
LIBPATH=/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/lib:/opt/freeware/lib:/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.8.5:/opt/freeware/lib/pthread/ppc64
```

still it is not working.

I found a reference to it https://sourceforge.net/p/slo/feature-requests/4/. but it is not helpful.

Edit: seems like libstdc++ is causing issue on the AIX7.1. we have system libstdc++ and libstdc++ of gcc4.8.5. when I link to system libstdc++ gdb runs successfully but my program fails but when i set path to libstdc++ in gcc4.8.5. GDB doesn't run but my executable runs. seems like system libstdc++ and gcc4.8.5 libstdc++ are not compatible.

Comment: Where did you get this `libadobelinguistic.a` file from?

Comment: shared location. perforce. corresponding file of linux is working fine. there is no error on Linux machine with gcc4.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with libstdc++. By default `LIBPATH` was set to `opt/freeware/lib` where `libstdc++` was available. While compiling my source was getting linked to libstdc++ available at the 'opt/freeware/lib' location. where as at run time it was looking for 'libstdc++' available in the gcc4.8.5. causing the issue.

setting LIBPATH to gcc `lib` directory solved the issue.

Comment: Please accept your own answer then, so the question isn't still open.